# How to reverse engineer the Twenty Eleven background image uploader?

Tags: theme-development, theme-twenty-eleven

I'm searching through the twenty-eleven theme's source files (functions.php and theme-options.php) attempting to get some clues on how to implement the upload utility found on several of the theme options pages. However, I can't find any reference to it.

Anyone know which file its contained in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the custom background, you'd call [`add_custom_background`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_background), for the cool header image things, it's [`add_custom_image_header`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_custom_image_header).  You need to hook both those into something like `after_setup_theme`:

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse27586_setup_theme' );
function wpse27586_setup_theme()
{
    add_custom_background();
    add_custom_image_header( 'some_callback_for_front', 'some_callback_for_admin' );
}
```

Add custom image header is more complex than it seems, so take a look in Twenty Eleven's `functions.php` file inside the function `twentyeleven_setup`, which starts around line 75, for some how to.  The code is very well commented.